# PhpStorm - unable to upload file to EC2 using SFTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpstorm, sftp

I have set up SFTP config in my PhpStorm and also added the connection via SSH.

Whenever I try to upload to the instance I get the following error in PhpStorm *(example of me trying to upload index.php file)*:

```
Could not write to "sftp://........./index.php
```

The above is located in `/var/www/html`.

If I change my deployment path to `/home/ec2-user` and then try to upload it works without error.

Then I have tried the following but that also doesn't work:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/html/
and chown
```

I have attached screenshot of my PhpStorm config as well. Wondering if anyone has any ideas about this.

[image: Connection image]

[image: Deployment path image]

[image: SSH Config]

Edit: Screenshot of permissions:

Inside var
[image: var]

Inside www
[image: www]

Example inside html
[image: Example file inside html]

Comment: Have you checked the permissions for `/var`, `www` as well? If `www` is 700(example) then it doesn't matter if you give 777 to `/html`. Check permissions for all the directories.

Comment: @Riz 
These are the permissions for those: 
[ec2-user@... ~]$ stat -c "%a %n" /var/
755 /var/
[ec2-user@... ~]$ stat -c "%a %n" /var/www/
777 /var/www/
[ec2-user@... ~]$ stat -c "%a %n" /var/www/html/
755 /var/www/html/

Comment: It's hard to udnerstand from the comment but I believe the permissions are there. In the question you said `and chown` but `chown` what? to `ec2-user`?

Comment: @Riz yeah thats correct to ec2-user: 
sudo chown ec2-user /var/www/html

Comment: can you do `sudo chown ec2-user: /var/www/html`. Also you said earlier that you have given 777 to `/html` but from the comment above it seems like it's `755`. `5` means read and execute but not write.

Comment: @Riz have habe now changed it to 777, also tried the command you sent and still doesn't work

Comment: @Mavreick1994, The problem is surely of permissions. You can check with `sudo -u ec2-user touch /var/www/html/testpage.txt` in your ubuntu machine. If it gives you permission denied(I expect) then you need to look better at the permissions. If it's the case, update the question(with screenshots) with permissions of all the directories till `/html`(included) please.

Comment: @Riz I did the command and nothing happened, testpage.txt was not created and no errors. 
I have added the screenshots

Comment: I don't know why it didn't create the test page but the issue is clear now. You already have a page `index.php` but it is owned by `root` and other users have only `read` permissions. You need to either remove it al together or change the ownership to `ec2-user` or/and make it writable(try with 777) and try again with your uplaod. Remember, all these steps are for testing. After the testing, you need to roll back the changes you have made to the permissions. You need to give only the necessary permissions to that group.